# Getting DirectoryIds via boto3 client

Tags: aws-directory-services

Trying to list the SimpleAD in my vpc but keep getting this error I am so fresh to this here is the code I'm trying to run.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client ('ds')
response = client.describe_directories(
    DirectoryIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    NextToken='string',
    Limit=123
)
print (response)
```

Here is the error:
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DescribeDirectories operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '[string]' at 'directoryIds' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^d-[0-9a-f]{10}$]

I'm just starting my adventure with python and aws so all help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you have the word 'string' you should put the directory id which will be in the form "d-" followed by 10 alphanumerics.  You can find this directory id in the AWS console where you've configured your workspaces' directories.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, so now I get it so that part was asking for a specific directory ID if I leave it blank like this ```  import boto3
client = boto3.client ('ds')
response = client.describe_directories()
print (response) ```   i get the lone  simplead i have how would i go about getting the id from the response to print is that two prints one underneath the other to get the ID?

Comment: Update the question and show what you're getting.